# Insert index column in table with large data

Tags: mysql, database

now i have a table with some columns and a large amount of data:

Table1

```
Column1        Column2  Column3
data1(string)  data2    data3
```

At the moment, the primary key is column1 typed with string. I need to add a new column Column0 with seriel interger, an index really. How can i do it using an mysql index?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to introduce the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN Column0 INTEGER(10)
```

The insert the ID in the new column in any way you want them; can be done by a script for example.

IF this is done, redefine the PK:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Insert the auto-increment:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 change column Column0 PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Make sure your auto_increment value is at the value your last id is:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = value_of_max_id+1_you_have;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
//First add a extra column.
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN column0 INTEGER NOT NULL;

//Fill the column with incrementing integers in the same order as the old index.
UPDATE table1 SET column0 = @rank:= @rank + 1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:= 0) init_rank
ORDER BY column1 ASC;

//Remove the old primary key.
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;

//Set column0 as the new PK.
ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE COLUMN column0 PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: @ulima69, yep all the lines, there is no `where` clause therefore it will not skip anything. The `order by` clause will make sure the lines are numbered in the same order that the initial index was in.